# How to get the Row Number in Excel using c#.net

Tags: c#-4.0

Hi Friends, 
            I am working with reading excel files, In my excel there are about 100 rows and i need to get the row number 58 in a int variable ? how to do it I have tried using this code but unable to get the row number ?

```
Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range) this.Application.ActiveCell;

//get the cell value
object cellValue = rng.Value;

//get the row and column details
int row = rng.Row;
int column = rng.Column;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the 58th row and first column value as below...

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelObj = null;
ExcelObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open("abc.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);

var value = (worksheet.Cells[58,1] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value;
```